# Copy a file from another app

Tags: android, file, android-intent, copy

I associated my app with a file extension `.vv` using this code:

```
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.vv" />
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Now when I open a file from DropBox for example, my app get launched and I can get the full path of the source file using:

```
this.getIntent().getData().getPath()
```

However when I try to read or copy it in any way (directly from path, or from the uri using `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)`, I have an EACCES exception on the source file.
I don't have this exception when I open it from the GMail app, but from DropBox I get it.

How can I read/copy it then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use        "Uses permission write external storage"

```
<application>
    ...

</application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</manifest>
The uses-permission tag needs to be outside the application tag.
```

Comment: Thanks it works. However I don't really get it, cause I don't wanna write but read. I didn't use this permission beacause "Starting in API level 19, this permission is not required to read/write files in your application-specific directories ...". Why is that permission needed to read ?

Comment: Any app that declares the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is implicitly granted this permission.

This permission is enforced starting in API level 19. Before API level 19, this permission is not enforced and all apps still have access to read from external storage. You can test your app with the permission enforced by enabling Protect USB storage under Developer options in the Settings app on a device running Android 4.1 or higher.